# Lightning attachment - Javascript Array push Scope issue

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Unable to print fileContents array values within a function. 
On upload file, i want to store file content in a js array then use whenever i need with in a function(like if condition below). But after the  doc.onload = function() scope, the fileContents value is not available. it prints empty array.

```
projects:function(component, event, helper){
var fileName = [];
 var fileContents =[];
var fileInput = component.find("fileId");
if(fileInput && !Array.isArray(fileInput)){
  var f = fileInput.get("v.files");     
  var file = f[0][0];
   fileName.push(file.name);
   var fileContent;
  var doc= new FileReader();    
  doc.onload = function() {
    var self=this;
       fileContent = doc.result;
    var base64 = 'base64,';
      var dataStart = fileContent.indexOf(base64) + base64.length;
      fileContent = fileContent.substring(dataStart);
      fileContents.push(fileContent);
      console.log('fileContents-----------------'+fileContents); //prints array with values
    };
    filer.readAsDataURL(file);
  if(somecondition){
     console.log('fileContents-----------------'+fileContents); //prints empty array 
   }
```

}

Any suggestion would be appreciated?.

Answer (score 0):

You've misunderstood how JavaScript works. When you call readAsDataURL, it is not called immediately, but instead called asynchronously. That means that the code after that:

```
if(somecondition){
    console.log('fileContents-----------------'+fileContents); //prints empty array 
}
```

Actually runs *before* the onload function, despite occurring later in the same function.

Let me demonstrate with an very short example how asynchronous calls work:

```
console.log('Point 1');
setTimeout(() => console.log('Point 2'));
console.log('Point 3');
```

The output will be:

```
Point 1
Point 3
Point 2
```

However, in the interest of being Lightning-specific, I suggest that you always use an attribute to store values that will exist between life cycles. This will make sure that you can access the data when you need to.